# Unwrap enum when all variants are of the same type

Tags: enums, rust

Consider an enum definition like this:

```
enum Money {
    USD(u32),
    EUR(u32),
    CHF(u32),
    // many more...
}
```

Note that all enum variants are of type `u32`.

```
fn amount(money: Money) -> u32 {
    // ?
}
```

Can I generically extract the wrapped `u32` contained in a `Money`  instance without matching on all cases, if yes, how?

Comment: If this is a property of your type, you might consider redesigning it: combine `enum Currency { Usd, Eur, Chf, ...}` with `struct Money { currency: Currency, quantity: u32 }`

Comment: This use case is centered around a bad data modeling. Of course it's an example but the reason it matters is that you don't often (never?) need such accessor if your data are correctly modeled.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The example is purely illustrative. I'm designing a little toy language and I wondered how Rust handled this particular case.

Comment: Either you need a custom type to discriminate `USD(u32)` from `EUR(u32)` for example, because they are different, or these behave the same, and the whole purpose of your type is invalidated. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: You can do `unsafe {(std::mem::transmute_copy::<Money, u64>(self)>>32) as u32}`. Just tell nobody where you found it.

Comment: This specific `transmute_copy` dance works if your number of discriminants fits `u32` (`4_294_967_295`) ... Just saying ...

Comment: I believe that using `transmute_copy` here invokes *undefined behavior* because the layout of an enum is undefined. If nothing else, it assumes that the discriminant comes before the value, which isn't guaranteed. I strongly recommend not using it.

Comment: In case there's still a doubt: the `unsafe` trick can be considered as a joke or as a demonstration of the way enums are encoded,  but *not* as a proper snippet you should paste into your code.

Comment: Agree, here's the [The Default Representation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-default-representation) link, which says _Nominal types without a repr attribute have the default representation. Informally, this representation is also called the rust representation. **There are no guarantees of data layout made by this representation.**_

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to do this, unfortunately. The usual approach is to create an accessor method:

```
impl Money {
    pub fn amount(&self) -> u32 {
        match *self {
            Money::USD(amount) => amount,
            Money::EUR(amount) => amount,
            Money::CHF(amount) => amount,
        }
    }
}
```

At least this way you only have to do it once.

Comment: But IMHO this defeats the purpose of having a `Money` enum, because you get a plain `u32` without the knowledge of the currency at all. Yes it's possible, don't know if it's good :/

Comment: @hellow I'm inclined to agree. trentcl also makes a relevant comment on the question about the design.

Comment: Note that it's also possible to write it as `Money::USD(amount)|Money::CHF(amount)|Money::EUR(amount) => amount` (I don't pretend it's better but it's less verbose)